# How to use awk command to print multiple lines based on the matched and filtering condition

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, awk

I am trying to filter out the logs which are 7 days older than the newest log, for example, if the last section of log is 2024-02-13 then all the logs on 2024-02-05 would be removed.

The example log file:

```
* Server Name: myserver
* Date and Time: 2024-02-05 23:00:01
* Total Number of Child (PID): 4
* PID: 117703, Worker Threads: 46
* PID: 117704, Worker Threads: 30
* PID: 117705, Worker Threads: 30
* PID: 117809, Worker Threads: 30

* Server Name: myserver
* Date and Time: 2024-02-05 23:30:01
* Total Number of Child (PID): 4
* PID: 117703, Worker Threads: 46
* PID: 117704, Worker Threads: 30
* PID: 117705, Worker Threads: 30
* PID: 117809, Worker Threads: 30

* Server Name: myserver
* Date and Time: 2024-02-06 00:00:01
* Total Number of Child (PID): 4
* PID: 117703, Worker Threads: 46
* PID: 117704, Worker Threads: 30
* PID: 117705, Worker Threads: 30
* PID: 117809, Worker Threads: 30

.
.
.

* Server Name: myserver
* Date and Time: 2024-02-13 23:00:01
* Total Number of Child (PID): 4
* PID: 117703, Worker Threads: 46
* PID: 117704, Worker Threads: 30
* PID: 117705, Worker Threads: 30
* PID: 117809, Worker Threads: 30

* Server Name: myserver
* Date and Time: 2024-02-13 23:30:01
* Total Number of Child (PID): 4
* PID: 117703, Worker Threads: 46
* PID: 117704, Worker Threads: 30
* PID: 117705, Worker Threads: 30
* PID: 117809, Worker Threads: 30
```

Expected output:

```
* Server Name: myserver
* Date and Time: 2024-02-06 00:00:01
* Total Number of Child (PID): 4
* PID: 117703, Worker Threads: 46
* PID: 117704, Worker Threads: 30
* PID: 117705, Worker Threads: 30
* PID: 117809, Worker Threads: 30

.
.
.

* Server Name: myserver
* Date and Time: 2024-02-13 23:00:01
* Total Number of Child (PID): 4
* PID: 117703, Worker Threads: 46
* PID: 117704, Worker Threads: 30
* PID: 117705, Worker Threads: 30
* PID: 117809, Worker Threads: 30

* Server Name: myserver
* Date and Time: 2024-02-13 23:30:01
* Total Number of Child (PID): 4
* PID: 117703, Worker Threads: 46
* PID: 117704, Worker Threads: 30
* PID: 117705, Worker Threads: 30
* PID: 117809, Worker Threads: 30
```

I did try to use awk command, but it didn't work as what I want, and it just clear the whole log file.

My code is as below:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG_FILE="logs/worker_count.log"
TMP_FILE="$LOG_FILE.tmp"

# Extract the newest and oldest dates from the log file
newest_date=$(grep -oP 'Date and Time: \K[^\n]+' "$LOG_FILE" | tail -n 1)
oldest_date=$(grep -oP 'Date and Time: \K[^\n]+' "$LOG_FILE" | head -n 1)

# Check if either date is empty
if [ -z "$newest_date" ] || [ -z "$oldest_date" ]; then
    echo "Error: Unable to extract dates from the log file."
    exit 1
fi

# Convert dates to timestamps for comparison
newest_timestamp=$(date -d "$newest_date" +"%s")
oldest_timestamp=$(date -d "$oldest_date" +"%s")

# Calculate the difference in seconds
time_difference=$((newest_timestamp - oldest_timestamp))

# If the difference is greater than or equal to 7 days (604800 seconds)
if [ "$time_difference" -ge 604800 ]; then
        # Calculate the cutoff date based on the newest date minus 7 days
        cutoff_date=$(date -d "@$((newest_timestamp - 604800))" +"%Y-%m-%d %T")

        # Extract entries within the specified date range and remove old entries
        awk -v cutoff="$cutoff_date" '/^(\* Server Name:|\* Date and Time:)/ {
        server_name = $NF
        getline datetime
        if (datetime >= cutoff) {
          print "* Server Name: " server_name
          print datetime
          for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            getline line
            print line
          }
        }
      }
    ' "$LOG_FILE" > "$TMP_FILE"

        # Replace the original log file with the filtered entries
        #mv "$TMP_FILE" "$LOG_FILE"
else
        echo "No need to remove old entries. Time difference is less than 7 days."
fi
```

Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: Don't put elipses (`...`s) in sample input/output as that just makes it untestable and requires everyone else to remove them before they can use your example.

Comment: btw, I didn't really look at your code but the regex shouldn't test for the date line, otherwise it'll run the block at the wrong time. also, `datetime` starts with `*` which will make the comparison against `cutoff` always fail (`*` is never greater than a digit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `tac` and GNU `date`, reading the file backwards could be efficient:

```
tac "$LOG_FILE" |
awk -v RS= '
    /Date and Time/ {
        if (!cutoff)
            "date -d \""$(NF-4)" "$(NF-5)" -7days\" +%F%T" | getline cutoff
        else
            if ($(NF-5)$(NF-4) < cutoff) exit
    }
    { print ORS $0 }   
' |
tac
```

Comment: for safety, check `$(NF-4)` and `$(NF-5)` don't contain characters that could cause the shell invoked by awk to run `date` to do something dangerous

Comment: this code uses second granulatiy, leave out the `$(NF-4)" "` / `%T` / `$(NF-4)`  to use day only

Comment: @Megan notice that jhnc had to unnecessarily complicate their code by adding `/Date and Time/` to skip the block of ellipsis in your sample input/output - that's why it's important to not use ellipsis in examples because it forces us to either manually remove them before we can test our code (as I did) or write code to handle them exactly as you show in your question (as @jhnc did).

Comment: Nice ideas to a) only calculate the cutoff date once and b) exit when the cutoff date has passed.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks. I actually hadn't realised I didn't really need the `/.../`, I was just adding a sanity check against malformed blocks in general - but there'd be much less indentation without it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using `tac` plus GNU `awk` (which I assume you have since you're using GNU grep and GNU date in your code) for `mktime()` and `gensub()`:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tac "${@:--}" |
awk -v RS= '
    {
        date_time = gensub(/-/, " " , "g", $(NF-5)) " 12 0 0"
        secs = mktime( date_time )
    }
    NR == 1 {
        minSecs = secs - ( 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 )
    }
    secs >= minSecs {
        print ORS $0
    }
' |
tac
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
* Server Name: myserver
* Date and Time: 2024-02-06 00:00:01
* Total Number of Child (PID): 4
* PID: 117703, Worker Threads: 46
* PID: 117704, Worker Threads: 30
* PID: 117705, Worker Threads: 30
* PID: 117809, Worker Threads: 30

* Server Name: myserver
* Date and Time: 2024-02-13 23:00:01
* Total Number of Child (PID): 4
* PID: 117703, Worker Threads: 46
* PID: 117704, Worker Threads: 30
* PID: 117705, Worker Threads: 30
* PID: 117809, Worker Threads: 30

* Server Name: myserver
* Date and Time: 2024-02-13 23:30:01
* Total Number of Child (PID): 4
* PID: 117703, Worker Threads: 46
* PID: 117704, Worker Threads: 30
* PID: 117705, Worker Threads: 30
* PID: 117809, Worker Threads: 30
```

That will run orders of magnitude faster than calling GNU `date` once per input record.

The above assumes that when you say "7 days older" in your question you do literally mean **7 days** and not **604800 seconds** or something else which is why I discard the time from the input and instead use noon on every date for the comparison. You'll see the difference if you compare 2 dates that are 7 days apart but at different times of day if you use the above approach vs using the time of day from the input in the comparisons.

If you do want to factor time of day into the comparison then just change this:

```
        date_time = gensub(/-/, " " , "g", $(NF-5)) " 12 0 0"
```

to:

```
        date_time = gensub(/[-:]/," ","g",$(NF-5)" "$(NF-4))
```

Comment: is the "once per input record" re my answer? if so, I don't think it does (nor did the question code)

Comment: @jhnc OK, I took a look at your answer and no, you're only calling `date` once so my comment wouldn't apply to your answer.

Comment: @jhnc I try to avoid reading other peoples answers before posting mine as sometimes I find myself influenced into thinking about the problem in a way that I wouldn't have thought about it otherwise. In this case the approach that occurred to me was to calculate the epoch secs once per record so I just wanted to point out how much slower the equivalent would be if calling `date` instead of `mktime()`.